# Pyinstaller compiled binary runs from %temp% folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using `sys.path[0]` in my script to detect the folder my script resides in. I have no issues running the executing the .py file.

I then compile the script using pyinstaller and run it, it fails. I noticed that when exe runs, the `sys.path[0]` changes to %temp%. Looks like exe runs from %temp% directory. However, in another place I reference `sys.argv[1]` which does not change.

For example, I see the following when exe runs:

`sys.path[0] -> C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\Temp\<temp folder>`

`sys.argv[1] -> C:\path\where\exe resides`

Comment: Are you using the "One-File" mode of `Pyinstaller`? if so: `When started it creates a temporary folder in the appropriate temp-folder location for this OS. The folder is named _MEIxxxxxx, where xxxxxx is a random number.` (from the [documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operating-mode.html#bundling-to-one-file))

Comment: Yes, I am using the --onefile option.

Comment: So, what do you use `sys.path[0]` and `sys.argv[1]` for ?

Comment: Using `sys.argv[1]` to check for the existence of CLI argument. Not using `argparse` because there is no arg parsing required, the script just requires one argument to be passed to a function later. For `sys.path[0]`, the script loads external binaries that are stored in the same folder as the script, so I needed a to detect the path the script is stored in. I changed my code to `path = sys.argv[0]; path = "%s\\drivers" % '\\'.join(path.split('\\')[0:-1])`. It works now.

Comment: For future reference, you can check if your app is being run in a `Pyinstaller` bundle by checking `if getattr( sys, 'frozen', False ):`. And if so, the absolute path to the bundle folder is `sys._MEIPASS`.

Comment: Thanks @JohnAnderson I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: onefile making it run in temp folder : Darn it! how to change it to current folder where the exe was started from?